# Coffeescript for loop

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to convert some apple chart examples from javascript to coffeescript.  Having a tough time trying to figure out how to write this for loop in coffee script.  Thanks for any help in advance

```
for (scale = maxVal; scale >= 0; scale -= stepSize) {...}
```

Answer (score 28):

This loop will increment by the negative of stepSize.

```
maxVal = 10
stepSize = 1
for scale in [maxVal..0] by -stepSize
  console.log scale
```

However, if stepSize is actually 1, then

```
maxVal = 10
for scale in [maxVal..0]
  console.log scale
```

would produce the same result

Comment: You don't need `(0-stepSize)`, just `-stepSize` should be sufficient.

Comment: use `by 1` or `by -1` if possible.  CoffeeScript (I have version 1.10) creates extremely inefficient (and quite puzzling) code if it must figure this out at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

```
scale = maxVal
while scale >= 0
  ...
  scale -= stepSize
```

There's a good tool for converting JS to Coffeescript: http://js2.coffee/

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. It's helped me out a few times in the last couple days :)